# Assignment for class, but instructions for powershell and I have a mac, need help converting

Tags: bash, macos, powershell, bin

I'm not a coder, but I have an assignment in a class that is asking to use ms powershell, but I'm on a Mac. I have figured out the binbash...sort of. I'm asked to write a script...

```
"`n"
Echo "Hello Internet World! -- I am here"
"`n"
Echo "My Name is Norma and today is `r"
Get-Date
"`n"
ECHO "As a net admin testing is an important part of the job" 
"`n"
ECHO "You should check for IP information with ipconfig "
"`n"
ipconfig 
Echo "You should check connectivity with ping"
PING www.google.com    
ECHO "All done pinging google"
ECHO "This is a very simple program using windows powershell scripting"
```

I got it as...

```
#!/bin/bash
Echo Hello Internet World! -- I am here
Echo My Name is Dawn and today is $(date)
ECHO As a net admin testing is an important part of the job
ECHO You should check for IP information with ipconfig 
ipconfig 
Echo You should check connectivity with ping
PING www.google.com
ECHO All done pinging google
ECHO This is a very simple program using Mac bin bash scripting
```

But when I run it, it won't stop pinging google.com. How can I get it to stop, so it will continue to "All done pinging google" etc?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can [run PowerShell on MAC](https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2016/08/19/run-powershell-on-mac-os-x/)

Comment: How? I'm a complete novice to this.

Comment: The link provided by @jrider above literally contains the full instructions for installing PowerShell on a mac

Comment: PowerShell for Mac, Linux, Windows. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Comment: `ping www.google.com -c 4`

Comment: That's not a particularly good Powershell script. I hope it's not a Powershell class.

Comment: Haha wow, since macOS has a case insensitive fs, the uppercase/mixcase commands actually work. As a fun side effect, it ends up running the external `/bin/echo` instead of bash's builtin

Comment: Thanks everyone. I just borrowed someone's pc to do this assignment. No it is not a coding class at all.